# Correct and Complete way to add Map in a Fragment which is a part of navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2, mapfragment

I implemented NavigationDrawer from the latest Android upgrade. Because of that I moved my entire application from different Activities to different Fragment. My activities used Maps and I implemented them by using SupportMapFragment but now I have changed my minimum SDK version and don't need the support library any more.

So currently I have made two Fragments which extend MapFragment and I am trying to add Maps to them by using a Fragment in the layout and then calling the FragmentManager and casting it to MapFragment followed by getMap().

I am stuck up in a null pointer exception and have tried the case in which the map would not have loaded. So I also checked if map is null. I am very confused now and  my code has become up a hodgepodge of multiple solutions. Can someone please guide me to the correct and complete way?

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private String[] mPlanetTitles;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test_activity);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items_array);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
                ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_websearch).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
         // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action buttons
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_websearch:
            // create intent to perform web search for this planet
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
            intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, getActionBar().getTitle());
            // catch event that there's no activity to handle intent
            if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.app_not_available, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* The click listner for ListView in the navigation drawer */
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

        if(position == 0){
            Fragment pf = new PickupFragment();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, pf).commit();
        }
        else if(position == 1){
            Fragment df = new DropFragment();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, df).commit();
        }

        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }


}
```

One of the MapFragments:

```
public class PickupFragment extends MapFragment {

    public PickupFragment() {
        // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
    }

    private Fragment fragment;
    static GoogleMap googleMap;
    static LatLng old_target;
    static Address pickup = new Address(new Locale("en","INDIA"));
    static Marker pickup_fav;
    static boolean infoWindowIsTouched;
    static boolean geocoder_working = false;
    LatLng center;
    Context context;
    View rootView;
    MapFragment pickupMapFragment;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_pickup, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        setupMap();
    }

    private void setupMap() {
      if (googleMap != null)
        return;
      googleMap = pickupMapFragment.getMap();
      if (googleMap == null)
        return;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        pickupMapFragment 
           = (MapFragment)fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map_pickup);
        if (pickupMapFragment == null) {
            pickupMapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance();
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map_pickup, pickupMapFragment).commit();
        }     
        googleMap = pickupMapFragment.getMap();
        context = getActivity();
        Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_next);
        button.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(4,180,4));

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(pickup==null || pickup.getMaxAddressLineIndex() == -1){
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Please select a pickup location!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    String full_address = "";
                    for(int i = 0; i < pickup.getMaxAddressLineIndex()-1;i++){
                        full_address += pickup.getAddressLine(i);
                    }
//                  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),address_text , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    CustomAddress c = new CustomAddress(full_address, Double.toString(pickup.getLatitude()), Double.toString(pickup.getLongitude()) );
                    Intent openDrop = new Intent(context, Drop.class);
                    openDrop.putExtra("pickup_address", c);
                    context.startActivity(openDrop);
                }
            }
        });

        TextView pickup_address = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_pickup);
        pickup_address.setText("");

        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googleMap.moveCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(19.1167, 72.8333),14.0f) );
        center = googleMap.getCameraPosition().target;
        googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(mOnCameraChangeListener);  
        pickup_fav = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(center).title("Melbourne").snippet("Test").
                visible(true).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.trans)));

        googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                infoWindowIsTouched = true;
                Toast.makeText(context,"info Window Clicked" + marker.getSnippet() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.addbookmark_layout);
                dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
                dialog.show();
                //
            }
        });
    }

    // An AsyncTask class for accessing the GeoCoding Web Service
    private class GeocoderTask extends AsyncTask<LatLng, Void, List<Address>>{

        @Override
        protected List<Address> doInBackground(LatLng... cur_center) {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context);
            List<Address> addresses = null;
            try {
                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(cur_center[0].latitude,cur_center[0].longitude, 1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return addresses;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            geocoder_working = true;
//          if(mapIsTouched)
//              pickup_fav.hideInfoWindow();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Address> addresses) {

            if(addresses==null || addresses.size()==0){
                Toast.makeText(context, "No Location found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{
                pickup = addresses.get(0);
                String full_address = "";
                for(int i = 0; i < pickup.getMaxAddressLineIndex()-1;i++){
                    full_address += pickup.getAddressLine(i);
                }
                TextView pickup_address = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_pickup); 
                CharSequence c = full_address;
                pickup_address.setText(c);
                geocoder_working = false;
//                if (mapIsTouched)
//                  pickup_fav.hideInfoWindow();
                old_target = googleMap.getCameraPosition().target;                  
            } 
        }
    }


    private final OnCameraChangeListener mOnCameraChangeListener = 
            new OnCameraChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
            LatLng x = googleMap.getCameraPosition().target;
            new GeocoderTask().execute(x);
            pickup_fav.setPosition(x);
            pickup_fav.showInfoWindow();
        }
    };
}
```

Layout file for the above MapFragment

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Pickup" >
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    </RelativeLayout>

 <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_pickup"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/from" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_pickup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <View
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:id="@+id/separator"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_pickup_search"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:src="@drawable/pickup_search" />

    </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.4dp"
            android:id="@+id/separator2"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

        <FrameLayout 
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:context=".Pickup" >

         <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map_pickup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
            android:name="com.sharedcab.batchcar.Pickup"
             />


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_center"
                android:layout_width="18dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/from" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_next"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:text="Next" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```